# Cascade in hibernate from the one to many side

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i know this question might be asked before, but i want to make it specific,

am using hibernate without annotations, so my case is if I've the following relation:

A has many of B and B has one of A, it's a one to many relation from A side, am dealing with A entity which contain set of B, then when Creating, Updating Bs in runtime using A, then  saving or updating A using hibernate, i want it also to save or update B i.e cascade save delete but from the side of A (one to many), i think it's allowed from B (many to one) side only

Regads,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question but it's definitely possible to define operations to cascade for a one-to-many association (see the section [6.2. Collection mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping)). Below, an extract from the [Chapter 21. Example: Parent/Child](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html):

> #### [21.3. Cascading life cycle](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades)
>
> You can address the frustrations of
>   the explicit call to save() by using
>   cascades.
>
> ```
> <set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="all">
>     <key column="parent_id"/>
>     <one-to-many class="Child"/>
> </set>
> ```
>
> This simplifies the code above to:
>
> ```
> Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
> Child c = new Child();
> p.addChild(c);
> session.flush();
> ```
>
> Similarly, we do not need to iterate
>   over the children when saving or
>   deleting a `Parent`. The following
>   removes `p` and all its children from
>   the database.
>
> ```
> Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
> session.delete(p);
> session.flush();
> ```
>
> However, the following code:
>
> ```
> Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
> Child c = (Child) p.getChildren().iterator().next();
> p.getChildren().remove(c);
> c.setParent(null);
> session.flush();
> ```
>
> will not remove `c` from the database.
>   In this case, it will only remove the
>   link to `p` and cause a `NOT NULL`
>   constraint violation. You need to
>   explicitly `delete()` the `Child`.
>
> ```
> Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
> Child c = (Child) p.getChildren().iterator().next();
> p.getChildren().remove(c);
> session.delete(c);
> session.flush();
> ```
>
> In our case, a `Child` cannot exist
>   without its parent. So if we remove a
>   `Child` from the collection, we do want
>   it to be deleted. To do this, we must
>   use `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`.
>
> ```
> <set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
>     <key column="parent_id"/>
>     <one-to-many class="Child"/>
> </set>
> ```
>
> Even though the collection mapping
>   specifies `inverse="true"`, cascades are
>   still processed by iterating the
>   collection elements. If you need an
>   object be saved, deleted or updated by
>   cascade, you must add it to the
>   collection. It is not enough to simply
>   call `setParent()`.

#### References

- [6.2. Collection mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping)
- [Chapter 21. Example: Parent/Child](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html)

Comment: Clear, Direct, well organized answer, Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Cascades work with unidirectional collections. Just add "cascade=all" or even cascade="all-delete-orphan" so that the child entity is deleted if it is removed from the collection.

Comment: so you mean i can add cascade=all at the one to many relation mapping file, and it'll handle updating childs?

Comment: yep, that's what it says in the hibernate docs. (see ch. 6, collections.)